# Maternal Mortality Ratio without healthcare

Tags: death, healthcare-data, childbirth

What is an estimation of Maternal Mortality Ratio (MMR, number of mother death per 100000 births) without professional healthcare? In other words, how often women die during childbirth in some wild tribes which do not use modern healthcare at all and give birth at home? Or for example what was the MMR in the past, when women all gave births at home without or with poor medical assistance?

I am asking, because I stumbled upon an estimation, which I do not believe to be correct in a book. The estimation was that one of 8 women would die during childbirth without medical assistance. The book is ["Brain Rules for Baby" by John Medina](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48332365-brain-rules-for-baby-updated-and-expanded).

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory thank you for your comment. Before posting the question I tried some quick googling and looked in Wikipedia. Now I am doing more thorough research for reliable sources on the subject.  However I am new on this particular stackexchange site so it is not clear for me, how I was supposed to go about asking my question. I mean that when I finish my finding and investigation of the sources, I am going to be able to answer my question myself. So should I not have posted the question until I knew the answer myself?

Comment: No, we don't require that you do enough research to answer your own question. We just ask that you show us what you've found so far, and the edit you made accomplishes that. The purpose of the requirement -- which you'll find on many exchanges -- is to avoid trivial, lazy questions that can be answered by the first hit on google.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is somewhere between 0.5% and 1% (about 500-1000 deaths per 100000 births). Below is the list of the sources I reviewed. Some sources provide higher estimates, but those should be attributed to unsanitary conditions in hospitals in the past (in the past births in a hospital were more dangerous than at home, because of contamination by the doctors).

- Chamberlain Geoffrey. [British maternal mortality in the 19th and early 20th centuries.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1633559/) J. R. Soc. Med. 2006;99:559–563.
- Loudon I. [Deaths in childbed from the eighteenth century to 1935](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3511335). Med Hist. 1986 Jan;30(1):1-41.
- Loudon I. [Ignaz Phillip Semmelweis' studies of death in childbirth](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3807776/). J R Soc Med. 2013 Nov; 106(11): 461–463; doi: 10.1177/0141076813507844; PMCID: PMC3807776; PMID: 24158918
- Max Roser and Hannah Ritchie (2019) - "Maternal Mortality". Published online at OurWorldInData.org. Retrieved from: 'https://ourworldindata.org/maternal-mortality' [Online Resource]